# How to attach pipeline to index

Tags: elasticsearch

I created ingest pipeline with adding timestamp according:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/my_timestamp_pipeline
{
  "description": "Adds a field to a document with the time of ingestion",
  "processors": [
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "ingest_timestamp",
        "value": "{{_ingest.timestamp}}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The pipeline above adds a field ingest_timestamp to every document with the value of the current timestamp.

PUT my_index/_doc/1

```
{
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

If we now retrieve this document, we can see that a field ingest_timestamp was added to it:

```
{
  "_index" : "my_index",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_version" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "foo" : "bar",
    "ingest_timestamp" : "2018-12-12T12:04:09.921Z"
  }
}
```

And how to attach pipeline to current index?

Comment: Do you mean how to add this value to all documents that already exist in the current index?

Comment: @VadimYemelyanov Yes, exactly.

Comment: Sorry for late answer- added below my suggestions) @caprio

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of updating all docs with that field you added

1. [Reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html). In general - very simple solution. **If you** need to save original naming of the index - you can :

   a) reindex to backup_index,
   b) delete original index,
   c) reindex from backup to new index named as previous one.

2. Kinda fake [update all docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) in you index. A little bit more tricky, you can try something like this.

   curl -XPOST localhost:9200/my_index/_update_by_query?pretty -d'{
   "script": {"inline": "ctx._source.foo = ctx._source.foo" }, "query": {
   "match_all": {} }}'

---

You can see from the example that the idea is to update value with same value. You can try your own field

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that in the first way I should add pipeline in destination index? e.g.

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "source",
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "destination",
    "pipeline": "set-timestamp"
  }
}
```

Though I checked through GET `new_index/_doc/1` doesn't show new timestamp fields.

Isn't it enough to just update index settings?

```
PUT /my-index-000001/_settings
    {
      "index" : {
        "default_pipeline": "set-timestamp"
      }
    }
```